# In a Google Doc, copy tables and paste data into them from values in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google Doc that I would like to use as a template for my project. I have multiple different tables in it, but there are two of them that I want to make copies of using Apps Script.

I would like to read the range of data in Column A of a Google Sheet and then create that many copies of Table 1 in the Google Doc. I would then like to repeat that same process for Column B of the Google Sheet and Table 2 in the Google Doc template.

I have the code to work for the first Table, but it always places the copies at the bottom of the document. I would like for it to be located immediately after the first one. I haven't been able to figure out how to do the process for the Column B and the Table 2.

I started with the below code, but it pastes the tables at the bottom of the document.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pasteTestSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  var values = pasteTestSheet.getRange('A1:A2').getValues();
  var docId = pasteTestSheet.getRange('D2').getValue();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  var table1 = doc.getBody().getTables()[0];
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  for ( var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    var copy1 = table1.copy();
    var table2var = i+1;
    copy1.getCell(0,0).setText(values[i][0]);
    table1.getParent().appendTable(copy1);
  }  
}
```

I've been banging my head into the wall for a while on this and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

[Here is the link to the test google doc template:](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FoCUCY_wi0sC7fW4lvwWBlhkIe59HzhhaufXyYKzYeg/edit#)

[Here is the link to the test google sheet template.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E3NKsimLSk1X20TsF-qJreFxPh45Hft6nuNaeOG_4uw/edit#gid=0)

Here are pictures to help. I bolded the text that will have placeholders fthat I would like to replace from the google sheet cells.

[Original Google Document Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA6R4.png)

[Google Sheet Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnWVH.png)

[Completed Google Doc Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFxaf.png)

[Completed Google Doc Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg6J2.png)

Comment: `and then create that many copies of Table 1 in the Google Doc`. You need to provide an example of the Google Doc, and of the Google spreadsheets, and an example of how a successful outcome should appear.

Comment: I'm unclear about what you want.  Do you want Table B to follow Table A for each row of the spreadsheet, rather than Table A one after each other then the Table(s) B after all the Table(s) A?

Comment: @Tedinoz I added the google doc and sheet links here. I tried to upload pictures, but it would only allow links to the pictures. Thank you!

Comment: @TheWizEd I apologize for not being clear. I hope that the above pictures and links help. I added the additional replace text functionality that I would like to incorporate as well. I'm having the hardest time with the tables and inserting additional ones in the correct spots. Ideally, I would like all of the iterations of Table 1 to be grouped together and then all of the iterations of Table 2 to be grouped together. There is other text that I want to remain untouched before, between, and after all of the tables. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of copying the table within the document.  I first make a copy of the template using `DriveApp` so the template can be reused in the future.  Then I create a seperate table for each entry in column A.  And then for column B.  To insert after the existing table I need to `getChildIndex()` of the current table and add 1.

I've modified my original answer to reflect the format of your spreadsheet.

And in answer to your question below, no.  I typically organize my data so that I only need to use 1 `getValues()`, see [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).  I then now how to index into that array to get the value or values I want.  Since you have 2 lists, one in column A and one in column H, since they can be different lengths I use the `if` to see if there are any more items in each list.

**Code.gs**

```
function copyTables() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName('Test');
    let values = sheet.getRange(3,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    let doc = DriveApp.getFileById("1eoLxiQ83L0y-NzzBmk8WTrd_TgO-v8r0-1Ks_530iXE")
    doc = doc.makeCopy();
    doc = DocumentApp.openById(doc.getId());
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let tables = body.getTables();

    // Table 1
    let table = tables[0];
    let copy = table.copy();
    values.some( (row,index) => {
        table.replaceText("{{Item Number Placeholder}}",row[1]);  // start in column B
        table.replaceText("{{Title Placeholder}}",row[2])
        table.replaceText("{{Item ID Placeholder}}",row[3])
        table.replaceText("{{Item Descriiption Placeholder}}",row[4]);
        table.replaceText("{{Item Picture Placeholder}}",row[5]);
        // either end of rows or entry in column is blank
        if( ( index < values.length-1 ) && ( values[index+1][0] === "" ) ) return true;
        table = body.insertTable(body.getChildIndex(table)+1,copy.copy())
        return false;
      }
    );

    // Table 2
    table = tables[1];
    copy = table.copy();
    values.some( (row,index) => {
        table.replaceText("{{Item Number Placeholder}}",row[8]);  // starts in column I
        table.replaceText("{{Title Placeholder}}",row[9])
        table.replaceText("{{Item ID Placeholder}}",row[10])
        table.replaceText("{{Item Descriiption Placeholder}}",row[11]);
        table.replaceText("{{Item Picture Placeholder}}",row[12]);
        // either end of rows or entry in column is blank
        if( ( index < values.length-1 ) && ( values[index+1][7] === "" ) ) return true;
        table = body.insertTable(body.getChildIndex(table)+1,copy.copy())
        return false;
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Results**

[image]

**References**

- [DriveApp.getFileById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String))
- [File.makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy())
- [Table.replaceText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#replaceText(String,String))
- [Body.getChildIndex()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getChildIndex(Element))
- [Body.insertTable()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertTable(Integer,Table))
- [Array.some()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I apologize that I forgot to change the sharing settings for the documents. I just changed them now. I tried to use the above code, but it doesn't seem to be working for my test document. I know that our sheets look different, but it doesn't seem to be copying the tables either. I probably did something wrong. My power keeps going off because of the storm so I will try to look into it more and understand with the references that you provided after the weather passes.

Comment: Okay, so I think that it is because the tables are set up differently and your code relies on an if statement for that end of the row or a blank entry in a column. Is it possible to do this in a different way? Manipulating these tables in the template document is only a portion of the entire project so there are many more rows and columns in the actual dataset that don't involve these steps. I guess that I can more clearly specify the data range at the beginning of the code and try to just integrate blank columns into my existing dataset if necessary. Thank you again for your help with this!

Comment: Thank you so much! It's inspiring to see what all you can do so I convinced my manager to get me a course so that I can better learn this material - very excited! I am trying to make sure that I better understand what you have helped me with. I tried to redo the whole process, but have the data tables transposed to test my understanding of the concepts. I have it copying the tables, but I can't get the replaceText function to replace with what I want. In your original example you used row[0] etc. Could you help me understand how to use the array properly here? Thank you!

Comment: `getValues()` returns a 2 dimensional array `values` of rows [ row0, row1, row2, ... ].  Each row is an array of cells, one cell for each column row0 = [ cell0, cell1, cell2, ... ].  The `values.some()` will execture the [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for each row.  So `row[0]` is the first cell in each row.

Comment: Thank you for answering this. So essentially, I would not be able to transpose this dataset and have the headers in a column with the data progressing to additional columns to the right. If the values.some() works for each row, then I wouldn't have control over which cells I want to use to replace the text because the dataset for each table is in a vertical line.

Comment: Of course you can. You would just need to transpose the array first.

Comment: Duh, I'm sorry for the dumb questions... I think that I have it working now, though! Thank you for all of your time and assistance with the first project and helping me better learn the concepts!